# Read from text file into ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I want to read the values of each rows in a textfile to a ListBox control.
The file needs to be uploaded on the client side.

I have the code to read from a fixed file but I don't know how to upload a file and then read from it.

The code to read from a normal file is:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo("file");
    StreamReader stRead = file.OpenText();
    while (!stRead.EndOfStream)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(stRead.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: so is your question actually "how do I upload a file"???

Comment: yes, but i dont want to save the file in my database.
Just read it and take the values from it.
Do i need to save the file somewhere ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this if I were you.  Hope this helps!

```
    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamReader stRead = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
    {
        while (!stRead.EndOfStream)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(stRead.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

BTW you'll need this in the aspx page:

```
    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="FileUpload1"/>
    <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" onclick="btnUpload_Click" Text="Upload" />        
    <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="ListBox1"></asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean but you can do something like ListBox1.Items[0].Text = "Whatever";

Comment: i mean can a user edit the values in the listbox (from the file)...
like change the name..

Comment: You can't edit it straight from the listbox you would have to load the selected listitem's text into a textbox first edit and then set the text property of the listitem to textbox.text.  This would only update the list though not the file.

Comment: One more thing...
The code works fine with .txt files bit not with the .doc and excel files. Can you help me with that

Answer (score 0):

To get a file from the client side, you have to use a file upload control.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/FileUpload10092005172118PM/FileUpload.aspx?ArticleID=79850d6d-0e91-4d7b-9e27-a64a09b0ee6b

The file upload has a stream of the file which you can read from.  However the user will have to point to the file.